# Problems with local server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning NodeJS and im trying to do a local server for a basic CRUD, but I don't know why this error appears in my console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0mEf.png)

I searched by myself in some pages but didn't get any solutions.

Also I noticed in this error that are trying to work with 2 directories:

```
"file:///C:/Users/James/Des"
```

```
"localhost/:1ktop/MySQL/app.js"
```

This is my "server.js"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiKcR.png)

I tried making this line up in my server.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/app.js"));
```

Also I add Enviroment Variables for my user in Windows.